# Select dictionary entries from dictionary with custom key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have Dictionary with a custom key as follows:

```
Dictionary<ClassOfEnums, AnotherClassofInformation> properties = 
    new Dictionary<ClassOfEnums, AnotherClassofInformation>(new ClassofEnumsComparer())
```

Where the key, ClassofEnums, is the following:

```
public class ClassOfEnums 
{
  Enum A;
  Enum B;
}
```

And AnotherClassofInformation contains a list of information. I add a bunch of entries to to the dictionary as follows:

```
Dictionary<ClassOfEnums, AnotherClassofInformation> properties = 
    new Dictionary<ClassOfEnums, AnotherClassofInformation>(new ClassofEnumsComparer())
    {
        { new ClassOfEnums {a=1234,b=6789}, new AnotherClassofInformation{...}},
        { new ClassOfEnums {a=0987,b=4680}, new AnotherClassofInformation{...}},
        { new ClassOfEnums {a=1234,b=1357}, new AnotherClassofInformation{...}},
        //and so on, where the hash of ClassOfEnums is unique for each record
    }
```

I have implemented a compare function, ClassOfEnumsComparer, per the documentation and online information about custom dictionary keys.

What I would like to do is select all of the entries from properties where, for example, key.a==1234 and return those as a new dictionary (or array). Yes, I could manually create other dictionaries that contain what I want, but I want to only maintain the one properties dictionary going forward because the data will evolve periodically.

Here is my first feeble attempt at this.

```
Dictionary<ClassOfEnums, AnotherClassofInformation> getSubsetofProperties(Enum q)
{
    Dictionary<ClassOfEnums, AnotherClassofInformation> p = 
        properties.SelectMany(x => x.Key.a == q).ToDictionary(new ClassofEnumsComparer()); 

    return p;
}
```

Is there another approach to what I'm doing?

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a short but complete example rather than pseudo-code... we can't tell why you're getting a compile-time error when we can't see your actual code. It's also not clear why you're trying to use `SelectMany` for filtering - that's what `Where` is for...

Comment: Have you tried this: properties.Keys.SelectMany(x=>x.a==q)... ? You might have to change the ToDictionary logic.

Comment: Based on Jon's comment and the accepted answer, I was missing the Linq syntax (name the Where) required for what I wanted. This was the intent of the original question, I'm new to Linq and utilizing lambda expressions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two recommendations.

First, if you're dealing with small data structures that are just a set of value types with no special comparison rules, use a `Tuple` instead of rolling your own class. So instead of something like `class MyKey { public int A; public int B; }`, just use a `Tuple<int, int>`. The hash and equality functions are already implemented for you.

Second, to answer your question, something like this will work.

```
var properties = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, AnotherClassofInformation>
{
    {Tuple.Create(1234, 6789), new AnotherClassofInformation()},
    {Tuple.Create(0987, 4680), new AnotherClassofInformation()},
    {Tuple.Create(1234, 1357), new AnotherClassofInformation()},
};

var filteredProperties = properties
                         .Where(e => e.Key.Item1 == 1234)
                         .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you!.

Comment: Michael, regarding the Tuple, thanks for the suggestion. However, my application is more in depth than my example and I have to use special comparison rules. But, again, thank you showing me the Where clause example. Like I said, I'm new to this part of C#.